# Kindly explain use of framezoom in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, zooming

I want to use `framezoom` to zoom in on India in this map. How can I do it? Can someone explain in a simple language (non-technical) the use of `\framezoom` function in `beamer`?

[image: prevalence of dyspepsia]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The general syntax for `\framezoom` is the following:

```
\framezoom<⟨button overlay specification⟩><⟨zoomed overlay specification⟩>[⟨options⟩](⟨upper left x⟩,⟨upper left y⟩)(⟨zoom area width⟩,⟨zoom area depth⟩)
```

The general idea of `\framezoom` is to generate a clickable rectangular area (a "button", if you will) over an image, so that when you click on the area, the zoomed detail will appear.

`<⟨button overlay specification⟩>` controls on which slide(s) of the frame should the button be created.

`<⟨zoomed overlay specification⟩>` allows you to specify on which slide(s) should the zoomed detail appear. The value(s) used here should not overlap the value(s) given in `<⟨button overlay specification⟩>`.

In the optional argument `[⟨options⟩]` you can use `border` or `border=<number>` to draw a frame around the part of the image that will be zoomed. The thickness of the rules used for the frame is controlled by the value specified in `<number>`; by default (i.e., if no options are specified) no frame is drawn; the color of the frame can also be changed, using `linkbordercolor` from hyperref (see second example below).

The clickable button has rectangular shape; the coordinates of the upper left corner of this rectangular area are given by `(⟨upper left x⟩,⟨upper left y⟩)`.

The width and the depth are given by `(⟨zoom area width⟩,⟨zoom area depth⟩)`.

#### Some examples:

(For some reason, the animations created from the resulting PDFs don't show the colored frame; however, processing the example codes, one in fact sees the frames).

First, a simple example: the clickable area is produced in slide `1`; it has a rather thick grey border; the upper left corner of the rectangular area is at `(6.8cm,1.2cm)` the width and depth of the clickable area are `1.4cm` and `1.5cm`, respectively. The zoomed area wll appear on slide 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\framezoom<1><2>[border=4](6.8cm,1.2cm)(1.4cm,1.5cm)
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{map}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a more sophisticated example; the frame around the clickable area has now a customized color produced using `\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={red!70!black}}`; the frame will appear on slide `2` and the zoomed image will appear on slide `3`; notice that slide `3` is now a `plain` one, so it contains no title nor headline/footline, and the zoomed image occupies all the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1,2>[label=india]
\frametitle<1,2>{A zoom over India}
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={red!70!black}}
\framezoom<2><3>[border=2](7.6cm,1.4cm)(1.4cm,1.4cm)
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{map.jpg}
\end{frame}

\againframe<3>[plain]{india}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative to `\framezoom` is to use the `spy` library from PGF/TikZ; here's a little example, showing the image and the zoomed area side-by-side (for details on the `spy` library, please refer to Section **49 Spy Library: Magnifying Parts of Pictures** of the pgf manual):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A zoom over India}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
spy using outlines={
  circle,
  magnification=10,
  size=5cm,
  connect spies}]
\node[inner sep=0pt] {\pgfimage[width=0.4\textwidth]{map}};
\only<2>{\spy[red!70!black] on (0.88,0.15) in node at (.5\textwidth,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The image I used in my examples is not the best one; the zoomed areas are pixelated. If possible, use a better image in your actual code.