# How to focus parts of table on a beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a table that  contains lots of number on it. I want to use it in a beamer presentation and I wonder whether it is possible to focus different regions at different slides. This is the  code I use for creating the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\caption*{Data statistics Treebanks} 
\medskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    *{2}{l*{5}{r}}}
\toprule
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} &
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} \\
\cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-12} 
ar & 1   & 4 & 2  & 123 & 123123 &
es & 123 & 902 & 123  & 234 & 31567  \\
bg & 3425  & 45  & 234  & 5252  & 1231634 &
pt & 755 & 234 & 645  & 2464  & 242  \\
cs & 767 & 23  & 86 & 345453 & 23422 &
sk & 3453  & 1231 & 235  & 43243 & 34663  \\
en &     &   &    &     &     & 
sl &     &   &    &     &      \\
et &     &   &    &     &     & 
ru &     &   &    &     &      \\
fr &     &   &    &     &     & 
hi &     &   &    &     &      \\
hu &     &   &    &     &     & 
lv &     &   &    &     &      \\
ro &     &   &    &     &     & 
nl &     &   &    &     &      \\
tr &     &   &    &     &     & 
pl &     &   &    &     &      \\
hr &     &   &    &     &     & 
de &     &   &    &     &      \\
it &     &   &    &     &     & 
gr &     &   &    &     &      \\
da &     &   &    &     &     & 
la &     &   &    &     &      \\
ca &     &   &    &     &     & 
ko &     &   &    &     &      \\
fi &     &   &    &     &     & 
ir &     &   &    &     &     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It creates the following table:

[image]

So, I want to focus on lets say here in one slide:

[image]

And this part in another slide:

[image]

Is there a way to do that  like this ?

Comment: with `tikzmark` library? search for question with this tag. here is many similar question ...

Comment: Yes, with `\framezoom`. (Or with the `spy` library in Ti*k*Z.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather simple way is to use the `\framezoom` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor={red}} % see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130110/121799
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{A table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    *{2}{l*{5}{r}}}
\toprule
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} &
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} \\
\cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-12} 
ar & 1   & 4 & 2  & 123 & 123123 &
es & 123 & 902 & 123  & 234 & 31567  \\
bg & 3425  & 45  & 234  & 5252  & 1231634 &
pt & 755 & 234 & 645  & 2464  & 242  \\
cs & 767 & 23  & 86 & 345453 & 23422 &
sk & 3453  & 1231 & 235  & 43243 & 34663  \\
en &     &   &    &     &     & 
sl &     &   &    &     &      \\
et &     &   &    &     &     & 
ru &     &   &    &     &      \\
fr &     &   &    &     &     & 
hi &     &   &    &     &      \\
hu &     &   &    &     &     & 
lv &     &   &    &     &      \\
ro &     &   &    &     &     & 
nl &     &   &    &     &      \\
tr &     &   &    &     &     & 
pl &     &   &    &     &      \\
hr &     &   &    &     &     & 
de &     &   &    &     &      \\
it &     &   &    &     &     & 
gr &     &   &    &     &      \\
da &     &   &    &     &     & 
la &     &   &    &     &      \\
ca &     &   &    &     &     & 
ko &     &   &    &     &      \\
fi &     &   &    &     &     & 
ir &     &   &    &     &     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\only<2>{
\framezoom<2><3>[border=4](0cm,0.8cm)(5.6cm,1.05cm)
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second slide will then be

[image]

If you remove the `\only` thingy, the last third slide will be zoom of the relevant part.

[image]

If you don't want to guess the coordinates and/or not zoom, you could do as @Zarko suggests, namely draw the boundary with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$%\tikznodestyle 
  #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{A table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    *{2}{l*{5}{r}}}
\toprule
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} &
\textbf{lang} & \mc{\textbf{train}} & \mc{\textbf{dev}} 
  & \mc{\textbf{test}} & \mc{$|\mathbf{T}|$} & \mc{$|\mathbf{F}|$} \\
\cmidrule{1-6} \cmidrule{7-12} 
\tikznode{ar}{ar} & 1   & 4 & 2  & 123 & \tikznode{tr}{123123} &
es & 123 & 902 & 123  & 234 & 31567  \\
\tikznode{bg}{bg} & 3425  & 45  & 234  & 5252  & \tikznode{br}{1231634} &
pt & 755 & 234 & 645  & 2464  & 242  \\
cs & 767 & 23  & 86 & 345453 & 23422 &
sk & 3453  & 1231 & 235  & 43243 & 34663  \\
en &     &   &    &     &     & 
sl &     &   &    &     &      \\
et &     &   &    &     &     & 
ru &     &   &    &     &      \\
fr &     &   &    &     &     & 
hi &     &   &    &     &      \\
hu &     &   &    &     &     & 
lv &     &   &    &     &      \\
ro &     &   &    &     &     & 
nl &     &   &    &     &      \\
tr &     &   &    &     &     & 
pl &     &   &    &     &      \\
hr &     &   &    &     &     & 
de &     &   &    &     &      \\
it &     &   &    &     &     & 
gr &     &   &    &     &      \\
da &     &   &    &     &     & 
la &     &   &    &     &      \\
ca &     &   &    &     &     & 
ko &     &   &    &     &      \\
fi &     &   &    &     &     & 
ir &     &   &    &     &     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\only<2>{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[draw,red,fit=(ar) (bg) (tr) (br)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The focus could be a color background ?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=5,height=5,scale=.5,debug]{beamerposter}
\def\grco{}\def\reco{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\only<2,4>{\def\grco{\rowcolor{green!30}}}
\only<3,4>{\def\reco{\rowcolor{red!30}}}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\\grco
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & 34\\\reco
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44\\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also wonder weather is it possible to highlight background as in the first screenshot I shared in my question? I mean half of the two rows (consecutive or not) the half of the lines that starts with `ar` and `bg`

Comment: @zwlayer You can use `\cellcolor` instead of  `\rowcolor` in the definition of  \grco, for instance,  then use in every `\grco` highlighted cell, e.g., `\grco 11 & \clco 12 & 12 & 14 \\ ....`